# IndexError: index n is out of bounds for axis 1 with size n

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, index-error

I have an empty matrix `M.shape`:

`(179, 179)`

Now I want to populate it using the following loop:

```
for game in range(len(games)-1):

    df_round = df_games_position[df_games_position['rodada_id'] == games['rodada_id'][game]]
    players_home = df_round[df_round['time_id'] == games['time_id'][game]]
    players_away = df_round[df_round['time_id'] == games['adversario_id'][game]]
    
    count=0
    for j_home in range(len(players_home)):
        count_fora=0
        for j_away in range(len(players_away)):
            score_home = 0
            score_away = 0
            
            points_j_home = players_home['points_num'].iloc[j_home]
            points_j_away = players_away['points_num'].iloc[j_away]
            print ('POINTS HOME',points_j_home)
            print ('POINTS AWAY',points_j_away)
            
            soma =  points_j_home + points_j_away 
            if soma != 0:
                score_home = points_j_home / soma
                score_away = points_j_away / soma
                print ('SCORE HOME', score_home)
                print ('SCORE AWAY',score_away)
            
            j1 = players_home['Rank'].iloc[j_home].astype('int64')
            j2 = players_away['Rank'].iloc[j_away].astype('int64')
            print ('j1',j1)
            print ('j2',j2)
                
            M[j1,j1] = M[j1,j1] + games['goals_home_norm'][game] + score_home
            M[j1,j2] = M[j1,j2] + games['goals_away_norm'][game] + score_away
            M[j2,j1] = M[j2,j1] + games['goals_home_norm'][game] + score_home
            M[j2,j2] = M[j2,j2] + games['goals_away_norm'][game] + score_away
            
            print (M)
            
            count+=1
            print ('COUNT', count)
```

Finally I get the error:

```
M[j1,j2] = M[j1,j2] + games['gols_fora_norm'][game] + score_home
IndexError: index 179 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 179
```

---

My last iteration round of prints:

```
COUNT 3
SCORE HOME 0.0
SCORE AWAY 0.0
j1 7
j2 162
[[0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 ...
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.         8.57263145]]
COUNT 4
SCORE HOME 0.0
SCORE AWAY 0.0
j1 7
j2 179
```

---

What am I missing?

Comment: "IndexError: index 179 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 179" What do you think is the smallest index that should be in bounds? What do you think is the largest index that should be in bounds? Why? Does it work that way for the built-in Python lists? Does it work that way in Javascript? Does it work that way in other languages you use?

Answer (score 0):

Matrix is `numpy` `array`, and the `index` for it is start with 0 not 1

```
np.array([1,2,3,4]).shape
Out[29]: (4,)
np.array([1,2,3,4])[3]
Out[30]: 4
```

We can simple fix it create the empty M with shape (180,180)

```
M = M[1:,1:]
```

Comment: @8-BitBorges simple fix , create M with shape (180,180), after assign M= M[1:,1:]

Comment: I see. would you be so kind as to edit your answer using the code above, after assign line?

Comment: I did it, and now I get the error `IndexError: index 178 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 178`...

Comment: @8-BitBorges since you already have the empty M 180,180178 should not exceed ...